# String replace &amp with & in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a script(Perl) which is taking a string from database through a variable and  writing to a xml file. if the string contain  **"&"**  then while opening xml file it is giving parser error  want to replace **"&"** with  **&amp**  through Perl script.

This is what I have tried

```
foreach my $ActiveLinkInfo ( @ActiveLinkInfos ) {

    my ( $SubCID, $Subf, $Subt, $Subclosed, $SubCName ) = (
        $ActiveLinkInfo->{'SubCID'},
        $ActiveLinkInfo->{'Subf'},
        $ActiveLinkInfo->{'Subt'},
        $ActiveLinkInfo->{'Subclosed'},
        $ActiveLinkInfo->{'SubCName'}
    );

    #@$ActiveLinkInfo

    if ( $Subf eq "HEADING" ) {
        push( @menu, { "Name" => "$SubCName", "Dir" => "HEADING" } );
    }
    else {
        my $res = GetChildren( "$path$SubCID\\", $SubCID, $VID );
        $SubCName =~ s/ - .*//;
        push( @menu, { "Name" => "$SubCName", "Dir" => "$SubCID/default.aspx" } );
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, so what have you tried for that?

Comment: No i am not able to fix i want to replace the string   like HP&HEV to  HP&amp;HEV then the Xml will open correctly

Comment: Please post your code which you have tried so far.

Comment: All you need to do is study [how to search and replace strings in Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Search-and-replace).

Comment: foreach my $ActiveLinkInfo (@ActiveLinkInfos)
   {
    my ($SubCID, $Subf, $Subt, $Subclosed, $SubCName) = ($ActiveLinkInfo->{'SubCID'},$ActiveLinkInfo->{'Subf'},$ActiveLinkInfo->{'Subt'},$ActiveLinkInfo->{'Subclosed'},$ActiveLinkInfo->{'SubCName'});#@$ActiveLinkInfo
    if($Subf eq "HEADING")
    {
     push(@menu, {"Name"=> "$SubCName", "Dir"=>"HEADING"});
    }
    else
    {
     my $res = GetChildren("$path$SubCID\\", $SubCID, $VID);
     $SubCName =~ s/ - .*//;
     push(@menu, {"Name"=> "$SubCName", "Dir"=>"$SubCID/default.aspx"});
    }
   }

Comment: Please edit your post with code - comments lose formatting.

Comment: I added your code to the question. That was not easy as there are comments in it, and there were invisible characters that I needed to delete in order to format it properly with perltidy. Your code also does not compile.

Comment: I'm confused. There is nothing in your code that reads from a database, opens a file or writes XML to a file - so I really don't see how it relates to your question. Please give a lot more detail.

Comment: @simbabque: Your edit didn't compile because you deleted one of the commas along with the extended ASCII character

Comment: @Borodin while that is the case, that's not what I meant. `@menu`, `$path` and `$VID` are not declared. Also you broke it again with your fix, you deleted two `$` when you put the `,` in ;)

Comment: The code you posted has nothing to do with your question???

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to convert text to HTML, use [HTML::Entities](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::Entities).

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [`HTML::Escape`](http://metacpan.org/module/HTML::Escape) module, which only translates in one direction -- from text to entities -- but does it very quickly